# Вывод текста в цикле: как добавить новую строку в tkinter.Text на каждой итерации

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, text

Как сделать что бы с каждым шагом цикла совершался переход на следующую строку?

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

tex=Text(root, height=23, width=49,bg='black',font='System',fg='white',bd=0)
tex.place(x=3,y=25)
i=1
z=7
n=3
d=4
a=5
for i in range(z):
   text=('A',i+2,'=','(',n,'- 1)','*',d,'+',a)
   tex.insert('2.2',text,)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(z):
   text=('A',i+2,'=','(',n,'- 1)','*',d,'+',a)
   tex.insert('1.0','{}\n'.format(text))
```

Comment: попробуйте запустить и посмотреть на результат. Является ли это желаемым выводом по вашему?

Comment: Не совсем. Но ответом на вопрос - да.

Answer (score 1):

[`'2.2'` индекс](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-index.html) означает добавить перед перед 3-ей буквой на 2-ой строчке.  Чтобы в конец текста добавлять, можно использовать `end` индекс.

Чтобы текст с каждой итерации был бы на своей строчке, достаточно добавить `'\n'` в текст:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import Tk, Text

root = Tk()
text = Text(root, height=23, width=49, bg='black', font='System',fg='white',bd=0)
text.place(x=3, y=25)
n, d, a = 3, 4, 5
for i in range(7):
    text.insert('end', f'A{i+2} = ({n} - 1) * {d} + {a}\n')
root.mainloop()
```

Если вы хотите *заменить* текст в цикле, чтобы только одна строчка была видна на экране, то можно [`w.after()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) использовать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import Tk, Text

root = Tk()
text = Text(root, height=23, width=49, bg='black', font='System',fg='white', bd=0)
text.place(x=3, y=2)

def replace_text(i, n=3, d=4, a=5):
    text.delete("1.0", 'end')
    text.insert("1.0", f'A{i+2} = ({n} - 1) * {d} + {a}')
    if i < 6:
        text.after(500, replace_text, i+1) # replace the next line in .5 seconds

replace_text(0)
root.mainloop()
```